# What is the term for the '@' in Razor syntax?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

The material I've read generally uses phrases like 'use the @ character here to denote the start...' but I want to know what to call such a character. A coworker suggested the word 'token' but I don't think that's correct.

Comment: "at sign" (or "at" for short) maybe??

Comment: I'm asking what the term is for a (any) character which is used to flag a section of the code for some purpose (like parsing). For example, in the C# code: ` string.Format("Some Value: {0}", someVariable); ` the "{0}" is called a 'format item', or more generally a 'token'. What would the '@' be called in Razor?

Answer (score 5):

Brifely looking at the source code, the Razor team seem to refer to it as **Transition Symbol**.

In [SyntaxConstants](https://github.com/ASP-NET-MVC/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Razor/Parser/SyntaxConstants.cs#L10):

```
namespace System.Web.Razor.Parser
{
    public static class SyntaxConstants
    {
        public static readonly char TransitionCharacter = '@';
        public static readonly string TransitionString = "@";
    }
}
```

Also in [HtmlSymbolType.Transition](https://github.com/mono/aspnetwebstack/blob/master/src/System.Web.Razor/Tokenizer/Symbols/HtmlSymbolType.cs#L22):

```
namespace System.Web.Razor.Tokenizer.Symbols
{
    public enum HtmlSymbolType
    {
        ...
        Transition, // @
    }
}
```

Still, I doubt you can *formally* name it "Transition", it's seems more like an internal term of the parser to denote contexts switches (for example from HTML to C# and vice versa).